# Rails 4: Multi-level joins with ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

I am adding another layer of complexity to my data model. Previously:
A Country had many Stores, which in turn had many Products.

I am now introducing Cities so that:
A Country has many Cities which have many Stores which have many Products.

The data I work with contains Stores that may not have Products (yet), Cities that may not have Stores (yet) and Countries that may not have Cities (yet).

I want to query all Countries in which to find Products. (I.e. so I can fill a landing page with all Countries where it makes sense for a user to look for stuff.)

Previously (with Country > Store > Product), I used this, and it worked well:

```
Country.joins(:stores => :products).group("countries.id").having("count(products.id)>0")
```

But I cannot get my head around this additional layer (Country > City > Store > Product). For instance, this doesn't work:

```
Country.joins(:cities => :stores).joins(:stores => :products).group("countries.id").having("count(products.id)>0")
```

...yielding this error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'stores' was not found on Country
```

Can anyone help?

(I am trying to be as SQL-agnostic as possible, so if it can be done with ActiveRecord methods I would like to do it that way.)

Comment: did you get it working?

Comment: Yes, but with a different approach:

`Country.joins(:cities => {:stores => :products}).uniq`

That seems to throw out all Countries where no Cities, Stores or Products are found.

Comment: right, because joins already returns only countries with cities with stores with products, so `having` is redundant

Answer (score 2):

```
Country.joins(cities: [stores: :products])
       .group('countries.id')
       .having('count(products.id) > 0')
```

Because of the `joins` nature `having` clause is redundant:

```
Country.joins(cities: { stores: :products }).uniq
```